# How to switch between ad networks randomly?

Tags: android

I have an app and I want to add advertisement from few companies, such as tapjoy, inneractive... How to make them to be changed randomly?

UPD:
I want to display advertisement from few ad-companies. For example, in the screen A it is tapjoy, in 10-15 min in the same creen it goes Moblicx, in another minutes it will be Leadbolt...

Comment: Can you be more specific? I want to answer, "Pick an ad network at random and display an ad from that network." I don't think that would help you, but this is such a straightforward thing to do and you didn't explain what your issue is.

Comment: I updated, i hope you will find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Use [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/).  The [Developer's Resource](https://www.adwhirl.com/home/dev) has instruction for integrating with Android apps.

Comment: I dont want to use them, because of i dont want to be attached to one ad-company. There are always can be a situation when someone puts your ID in "click-click" app and you will get banned, and everything that was done will be loosed.

Comment: Please read what the site says. AdWhirl is not another ad company. It is just a mediation solution so that you can use whatever ad provider you want.